# Index-based assignment in the loop for Pair, C++

Tags: c++, std-pair

I am new to C++. I want to assign the values to my tuple inside the loop.
The following does not work.

```
#include<utility>

std::pair<int, int> myPair;

int main() {
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        std::get<i>(myPair) = i;
    }
}
```

How could I do it correctly?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That wouldn't help much, I think. Both support `std::get`.

Comment: @Python You could do `(i == 0 ? myPair.first : myPair.second) = i;`, but I don't see the point.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am reading the values in C++ from my Python program. The function that does this, returns a new value per loop iteration. I want to save those to process them later. Can I do it better than with pair/tuple?

Comment: Maybe use an array of two ints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a reason to insist on doing this in a loop? If not, you can just assign to `mypair.first` and `mypair.second`.

```
#include<utility>

std::pair<int, int> myPair;

int main() {
    myPair.first = 1;
    myPair.second = 2;
}
```

A very useful website to check what's available for standard library types is [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)

Maybe you actually want a `std::vector`?

```cpp
#include <vector>

int get_next_value(int); // Not defined in this example.
// You get your values from somewhere...

// note that global variables like this might not be the best idea.
std::vector<int> values; 

int main() {
    for (int i=0; i < 2; ++i) {
        values.push_back(get_next_value(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: As I explained in the comment under the quesiton:"I am reading the values in C++ from my Python program. The function that does this, returns a new value per loop iteration. I want to save those to process them later. Can I do it better than with pair/tuple?"

Comment: @Python I don't understand what you're saying. A `std::pair` has exactly two things inside. Do you need more than 2 things? You might be looking for `std::vector`

Comment: My function returns a new value per loop iteration. I want to save these values in my pair or tuple.

Comment: You said that. How many loop iterations will you have? Is it only two? Maybe you should provide a code example including your loop where you get the values. I updated my answer to include an example how to do it with `std::vector`.

Comment: you are right. `std::vector` does what I need!